# Replace an occurrence of a symbol from a file

Tags: c

The following code reads from a file the occurrences of the digit 1. My question is how could such an occurrence be replaced with another number (say '4') and written back again in the file. The while loop will be continued with?

```
int next;
    FILE *f;
    if (!(f=fopen("C:\\Test\\Sign.txt", "rt"))) 
            {   
              printf("File not existing\n");
            } 
    else{
        while((next=='1')!=EOF)
```

Comment: the code reads nothing at all from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper solution for that [including the initial one] would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int f(FILE *);
int main(){
    int num=0, next;
    FILE *f;
    if (!(f=fopen("C:\\Test\\Sign.txt", "rt"))) 
            {   
              printf("File not existing\n");
            } 
    else{
       for(;;){
        if((next=fgetc(f))== EOF) break;
        if (next == '1') num++;}
   }
        printf("Found occurrences of digit 1 are %d\n", num);
getch();
}
```

The for loop counts the occurrences of ones[in this case] whenever it passes through the number with fgetc assigned to the value of next which is 1.